# Fast way to remove some fixed number of keys from dictionary in python?

Tags: python

Is there a "fast" way to clear "k" keys from dictionary. These can be any keys.
Like for example, if I have to clear out a dictionary.. I can simply do `d.clear()` where `d= {}`.
But rather than wiping out the entire dictionary, I am wondering if there is a "fast" (constant Order) way to randomly remove "k" keys from dictionary?

Comment: In a word... no. (Actually, `dict.clear()` is also not constant order but linear, there is [a loop](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b509d52083e156f97d6bd36f2f894a052e960f03/Objects/dictobject.c#L1657) in the C code.)

Comment: maybe keeping 10% is a little bit faster?

Comment: @YongkangZhao please elaborate. That could work ?

Comment: You mean remove a Kth element? something like indices in lists?

Comment: hum, I thought I saw you mentioned removing 90% of keys, maybe just randomly pick 10% of keys and make a new dict with those key and value and replace it with the original dict.

Comment: @YongkangZhao: yeah.. i thought if one is possible, other is possible too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something such as this be your answer?

```
from random import sample

d = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2, 'doo': 3, 'tak': 4}

def rand_clear(data, k):
    return dict(sample(data.items(), k=len(d)-k))

print(rand_clear(d, k=1))
```

Results

```
{'foo': 1, 'doo': 3, 'tak': 4}
```

**Note:** This doesn’t remove any items, it merely creates a new dict with randomly selected items.

If you truly want to delete random items it’s easy enough to do from the above code:

```
def rand_clear(data, k):
    for key in sample(list(data), k=k):
        del data[key]
```

This is going to be faster than the first method

Comment: You can actually do `dict(sample(data.items(), k=k))` to avoid the `list` call.

Comment: @GZ0 Yeah.. I was wondering the same.. seems like conversion to list can be avoided

Comment: Ahh perfect I didn’t even think of that! I’ll change

Comment: Note that this _keeps_ `k` values, not _clears_ `k` values. (It is trivial to switch though.) It is also non-destructive: it will not remove any elements, but construct another dict without them. And it is not constant time; as I said before, it is impossible to do that. That said, it is very likely this is adequate, anything more is almost certainly premature optimisation.

Comment: @Amandan I changed k from k to len(d)-k so it correctly essentially removes k items not returns k items. You’re right also about it constructing another dict although this seemed to be the most optimal solution for most cases. Although one could easily made it replace data in the method or set d to the result of the function. This was merely for example sake.